# How to remove html extension from file using htaccess provided by WordPress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to remove .html from url which aren't posted using WordPress using below code :-

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
```

And the htaccess provided by WordPress is :-

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

The html file I am trying to remove html extension from is not a post but external file uploaded in c panel, any help would be greatly helpful thanks! [embers of divinity](https://mangareadhere.xyz/manga/RW1iZXJzIG9mIERpdmluaXR5)

Comment: So what is the actual issue you have when using that attempt you implemented?

Comment: @arkascha it throws 404 error

Comment: Please post the _final_ rule set you implemented along with test URL that shows that behavior, add that information to the question by editing it. Thanks.